# Need VBA/Macro code to hide rows with 0 values in columns

Tags: vba, excel

I only want rows to be visible if any of the cells from B9:AF54 and B60:AF129 have values greater than 0.

For example if the whole row has 0 for every corresponding column, I want it hidden. If any cells in the row has a value of 1 or higher, I want them to be visible.

Comment: What rows you want to hide? The condition requires every cell equal to 0? Or just One cell in particular row is enough to hide the row? What have you tried so far? What is the logic behind all this?

Comment: the description of your requirement is very unclear. please think about what you asked . then think about what you want to ask. then update your post.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn updated! I've tried using a helper column to just sum up the values from B:AF but I dont know how to automate it.

Comment: @jsotola updated!

Comment: much better ... maybe take out the reference to A:A also, it makes no sense to have it there `I only want rows to be visible ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub HideRows()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim hide As Boolean
'loop through rows
For i = 9 To 54
    hide = True
    'loop in the row: B through AF column
    For j = 2 To 32
        'if we found value greater then zero, then we don't want to hide this row
        If Cells(i, j).Value > 0 Then
            hide = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

    Rows(i).Hidden = hide
Next i

'loop thorugh second range
For i = 60 To 129
    hide = True
    'loop in the row: B through AF column
    For j = 2 To 32
        'if we found value greater then zero, then we don't want to hide this row
        If Cells(i, j).Value > 0 Then
            hide = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

    Rows(i).Hidden = hide
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Any way I can unhide all rows with a button too?

Comment: Just put following code wherever you need: `For i = 1 To Rows.Count   Rows(i).Hidden = False    Next i`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks so much!!

Comment: By any chance, does filtering also work for columns?

Comment: Yes, just google `Hiding columns, Excel VBA` and it will get you lots of code like one I provided :)